# How to call a variable within {!! !!} in Laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, variables, laravel, laravel-blade

I have this:

```
<title>{!!Config::get('lang_en.title')!!}</title>
```

I want to do somethnig like this:

```
<title>{!!Config::get('lang_{{$language}}.title')!!}</title>
```

Is it possible ?

Comment: try <?php echo Config::get('lang_'.$language.'.title');?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the general thing you need to understand is that anything inside `{!!` `!!}` is normal PHP, not Blade templating.

So you would concatenate variables the same way you would in PHP, as your accepted answer shows:

```
'lang_' . $language . '.title'
```

Basically `{!!` X `!!}` gets converted to `<?php echo` X `; ?>`

And `{{` X `}}` gets converted to `<?php echo htmlentities(` X `); ?>`

---

`{{ }}` is safer and should always be used if the string contains user input. `{!! !!}` should be used if the string contains HTML. What if it's a mix of both?

Then you should use `{!! !!}` so that the HTML works, but wrap the user input with the `e()` function, e.g.

```
// In the controller
$string = '<span>' . e($username) . '</span>';

// In the view
{!! $string !!}
```

`e()` is just Laravel shorthand for `htmlentities()`.

Comment: Thank you for that answer. So, this means that the **{{ X }}** is more secure for use than **{!! X !!}** ?

Comment: @YasenIvanov You're welcome. Yes that's correct. But of course you can't put HTML inside {{ }}. I updated the answer to show what you can do in that case

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
{!!Config::get('lang_' . $language . '.title')!!}
```

by removing curly brackets and append the value as a string

Comment: @YasenIvanov {!!Config::get('lang_en.title')!!} is it working?

Comment: check what is written in the converted php file.

Comment: Sorry, i mislead you. The first solution works properly, but I needed to made some changes in the other php file. Thank you !